# ray_ground_filter differing from specification?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking at the implementation for the [ray_ground_filter for Autoware.AI](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/core_perception/blob/master/points_preprocessor/nodes/ray_ground_filter/ray_ground_filter.cpp), while also reading the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master/src/perception/filters/ray_ground_classifier/design/ray-ground-classifier-design.md) (from Autoware.Auto, referred by the Autoware.AI repo).

From the documentation, if the current point is not within the local cone it will only be set as 'ground' if it is distant by a minimum threshold and, at the same time, is within the global cone.

However, the code is comparing the current height with the *local cone height* instead of the *global cone height*.
I believe this comparison is in [line 197](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/core_perception/blob/master/points_preprocessor/nodes/ray_ground_filter/ray_ground_filter.cpp#L197) of the code (commit 4bf37a8).

Shouldn't it be comparing:

`(current_height <= general_height_threshold && current_height >= -general_height_threshold)`

instead of the current:

`(current_height <= height_threshold && current_height >= -height_threshold)`?

Otherwise, am I missing something on how this is compliant with the documentation?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359694/ray_ground_filter-differing-from-specification?/) by [pedroexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/51367/pedroexe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2020-08-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-08-20**:
@TakaHoribe can you comment on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked my colleague who is familiar with this algorithm and compared the original paper. Yes, it is a bug. As you say, [this line](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/core_perception/blob/master/points_preprocessor/nodes/ray_ground_filter/ray_ground_filter.cpp#L197) should be fixed to replace `height_threshold` with `general_height_threshold`.

Our team is taking this issue, so will be fixed soon.

Thank you very much for your report and sorry for the late response.

---

Originally posted by [TakaHoribe](https://answers.ros.org/users/42648/takahoribe/) with karma: 181 on 2020-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pedroexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/51367/pedroexe/) on 2020-11-20**:
Great! Thanks for confirming.